# Access to path is denied when trying to upload file from localhost in IE in Asp.net MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, file-upload

Strange problem: My Asp.net MVC app has a file upload page where the user selects a file to upload, submits and that's about it. (PS. This is a normal input type='file' scenario, no funny business)

This works in the following conditions:

**Localhost (accessed locally)**
Firefox (works)
Chrome (works)
***IE however doesn't work "Access to path ... is denied. See stack trace below.***

**Browsing to the app on my machine from another machine**
Firefox (works)
Chrome (works)
IE (works)

Note: this has nothing to do with file/folder permissions as it does work from other browsers or accessing the app from another machine.

Why would IE behave like this on my local machine?

Comment: Can you publisch the Stacktrace